# Projective closure of curve in $\mathbb{A}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, curves, projective-varieties

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider the curve $V(y^2 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x) = C \subset \mathbb{A}^2$.

Now, we know that its the zero locus of some ideal, from what I gather this ideal is principal but im not able to see this (how can I see this?).

Given that $C = V(I)$ for a principal ideal $I=(f)$, I want to consider its projective closure in $\mathbb{P}^2$ for $U_i = \{ (a_0:a_1:a_2) \in \mathbb{P}^2 : a_i \not= 0 \}$. Let's take $i=2$ for example, then $\overline{\psi_2(C)} \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ is closed subset defined by the homogeneous ideal generated by $\text{hom}_2(g)$ for $g \in I$. Note that we define $\psi_i: \mathbb{A}^n \to U_i$ by $(a_1,...,a_n) \mapsto (a_1:...:a_{i-1}:1:a_{i+1}:...:a_n)$ (when working over $\mathbb{A}^n$) which is a homeomorphism. So we are considering the closure of the curve $C$ under this homeomorphism.

Here I have a second question. Now, something tells me that this projective closure is just the zero locus of the homogenized polynomial $X^3 - 3X^2Z + 2XZ^2 - ZY^2$, but I am stuck trying to show this.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff missing or mixed up here. Let's try to clean it up and straighten it out. The line 

"$y^2=x^3-3x^2+2x=C\subset\Bbb A^2$"

has a type error - what you really mean is probably $V(y^2=x^3-3x^2+2x)=C\subset \Bbb A^2$. Next, $C$ is very much a closed set in the Zariski topology on $\Bbb A^2$ - from later in the post, it seems like you want to consider the projective closure of this and therefore embed $\Bbb A^2\subset\Bbb P^2$ and consider the image of $C$ under this embedding, but you don't *say that*. Can you edit your question to make it clear what's going on?

Comment: @KReiser As I understand from the text I am reading, curves are defined as set of points in $\mathbb{A}^n$, its not defined as $V(y^2 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x)$, indeed $y^2 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x$ is strictly speaking not a polynomial. 

How is this a closed set, under the zariski topology? We define closed sets to be the zero locus of homogeneous polynomials. For which homogeneous polynomial $P$ is $V(P) = C$?

Comment: I will edit to make it clearar on the embedding.

Comment: Saying $V(p=q)$ is a shortcut to saying $V(p-q)$. And you have mixed something up, because we only require that the polynomials defining an algebraic set be homogenous when we're dealing with something in projective space. An algebraic set in affine space can be cut out by any polynomial or collection of polynomials you like, with no homogeneity requirements.

Comment: @KReiser you are right, I missed that we construct closed sets in $\mathbb{A}^n$ with just any subset of polynomials from $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. Thanks for pointing it out. 

I will remove that part, as it (luckily) does not affect the nature of the questions.You are also welcome to edit details if you want, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @KReiser Is the terminology saying that $C$ is a curve defined by $y^2 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x$ really wrong..?

Comment: I am not going to edit your post to fix your issues because that might prevent you from getting help on it. And your second comment isn't quite right - the literal phrasing "$y^2=x^3-3x^2+2x=C$" is the issue - the left hand side of the equals sign is $y^2$, a polynomial, then the middle part is $x^3-3x^2+2x$, another polynomial, then the right hand side is $C$, a curve, an object which cannot be compared with a polynomial (no curve equals a polynomial - it equals the vanishing set of some polynomials, though). You want to write $V(...)=C\subset\Bbb A^2$ or the like.

Comment: @KReiser Ok sure, I agree with that, some parentheses would have fixed the confusion. Ill add that. 

Do you follow the rest of where I am going or is it still unclear?

Comment: Fine, you win, I'll edit your post to add the letter $V$ to make the line work. The rest of the post is reasonable. Here are some hints: do you know the nullstellensatz? How does homogenization behave with respect to products? That is, if $f=gh$, is there any relation between the homogenizations of $f$, $g$, and $h$?

Comment: @KReiser It's not about winning, I am just trying to learn and sort out the details along the way. 

Yes I do but I need to think about how to use it here, thanks for the hint(s).